# Randomly changing for loop values

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been working on a deep q learning snake game in my free time, with plans to add genetic algorithm components to it. To that end, I was setting up loops that would allow me to create a given population of snakes that would each run for some number of episodes for a total of some number of generations.

It should be simple. Just some nested for loops. Only, I've been getting some pretty wild results from my for loops.

This is the code in question:

```
def run(population_size=1, max_episodes=10, max_generations=50):
    total_score = 0

    agents = [Agent() for i in range(population_size)]
    game = SnakeGameAI()

    for cur_gen in range(max_generations):
        game.generation = cur_gen
        for agent_num, agent in enumerate(agents):
            # Set colors
            game.color1 = agent.color1
            game.color2 = agent.color2

            # Set agent number
            game.agent_num = agent_num

            for cur_episode in range(1, max_episodes+1):
                # Get old state
                state_old = agent.get_state(game)

                # Get move
                final_move = agent.get_action(state_old)

                # Perform move and get new state
                reward, done, score = game.play_step(final_move)
                state_new = agent.get_state(game)

                # Train short memory
                agent.train_short_memory(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, done)

                # Remember
                agent.remember(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, done)

                # Snake died
                if done:
                    # Train long memory, plot result
                    game.reset()
                    agent.episode = cur_episode
                    game.agent_episode = cur_episode
                    agent.train_long_memory()

                    if score > game.top_score:
                        game.top_score = score
                        agent.model.save()

                    total_score += score
                    game.mean_score = np.round((total_score / cur_episode), 3)
                    
                    print(f"Agent{game.agent_num}")
                    print(f"Episode: {cur_episode}")
                    print(f"Generation: {cur_gen}")
                    print(f"Score: {score}")
                    print(f"Top Score: {game.top_score}")
                    print(f"Mean: {game.mean_score}\n")
```

And this is the output it gives:

```
Agent0
Episode: 3
Generation: 7
Score: 0
Top Score: 0
Mean: 0.0

Agent0
Episode: 3
Generation: 14
Score: 0
Top Score: 0
Mean: 0.0

Agent0
Episode: 7
Generation: 20
Score: 1
Top Score: 1
Mean: 0.143

Agent0
Episode: 10
Generation: 26
Score: 0
Top Score: 1
Mean: 0.1

Agent0
Episode: 6
Generation: 28
Score: 1
Top Score: 1
Mean: 0.333

Agent0
Episode: 5
Generation: 37
Score: 0
Top Score: 1
Mean: 0.4

Agent0
Episode: 3
Generation: 43
Score: 0
Top Score: 1
Mean: 0.667

Agent0
Episode: 1
Generation: 45
Score: 1
Top Score: 1
Mean: 3.0

Agent0
Episode: 2
Generation: 49
Score: 0
Top Score: 1
Mean: 1.5
```

The generation number steadily ticks up every second until it hits 49 and ends the loop, while the episode number randomly changes every time the snake dies. It's bizarre. I've never seen anything like this and have no idea what in my code could possible cause it.

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: You only print episodes `if done:` so if not done then that episode is skipped. idk what an episode is in this case, maybe each time the snake moves one space? either way the reason it is not printing them all must be caused when `not done` is true.

Comment: Also, please explain your output because you said "generation ticks up steadily" but provided an output where that is not the case.

Comment: @jfaccioni I'm not sure what you mean. There's an "if name = main" I have that executes this function. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @EliHarold An episode is the life of a snake. So, a game instance starts. The snake runs around. It hits something, dies, and the episode ends.

As for the generation ticking up steadily, I can see that in the pygame screen that I have running. But the console output only prints at the end of each episode, so it doesn't show that the generation ticks up every second. Since the pygame code isn't the problem here, I didn't show it.

Comment: @GrantAllan so if the pygame code is not the issue what is the difference between saying `if done:` and `if True:` since the snake should die each episode? or does the snake not die when it wins? in which case that could be why it skips.

Comment: @GrantAllan I meant what environment you're using to run the code, e.g. if you're using Jupyter it could be due to variables holding values from previously executed (and possibly deleted) cells. But if you have a `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause you're probably not using Jupyter.

Comment: @EliHarold If I say if True: it will die immediately after it takes a step. The snake's agent class (the snake itself) checks to see if it dies. If it does, then it spits out the value "True" to done. I know this part of the code works perfectly. As for winning, well, there's no winning. It keeps going until it loses, so I don't need to have a win condition.

Comment: @jfaccioni No, it's a stock standard .py script. Good thought though.

Comment: @GrantAllan I think you have misexplained something here because changing it to `if True:` would only kill the snake if there were multiple episodes during the life of a snake, but you said one episode IS the life of the snake so this does not make sense.

Comment: @EliHarold Let me try again then. Snake is about getting as much food as possible without hitting a wall or part of the snake's body. You keep going until you die; there is no winning. An episode is one game; one life of the snake. That if statement is inside the for loop that acts as an episode. It checks the "done" variable to see if done is True (if the game is over). If we change it to if True, then the game will immediately end every time.

Comment: @GrantAllan exactly, if that is true the here is your issue: the loop `for cur_episode in range(1, max_episodes+1)` is NOT actually "the for loop that acts as an episode" it is iterating from episode to episode. (first loop `cur_episode` is 1, then next, 2, etc. so in other words if `done` is not `True` every iteration then you have multiple "episode" values during a single life of the snake.

Comment: @GrantAllan I assume you need to have a while loop after `for cur_episode in range(1, max_episodes+1)` that actually loops through the game states (right now the episode loop is doing that). Then you can do `if done:` `#your code here` `break`. This will mean episode increments only when the snake dies. (which you have said is the intention.)

Comment: @EliHarold That absolutely was the problem. I'm still baffled by what was going on with my generations ticking up every second and why the episodes jumped to random numbers, but they stopped being weird as soon as I fixed the game loop issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GrantAllan you're welcome I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

For everyone who doesn't want to go through the comments where
Eli Harold helped me work this out, the problem was that I had my code treating each episode like a frame of the game. So instead of an episode being the full lifespan of a snake (an entire game), every time the snake took an action was an episode.

Here's what my code looks like now. I added a run loop, which fixed the issue.

```
def run(population_size=1, max_episodes=10, max_generations=50):
    total_score = 0

    agents = [Agent() for i in range(population_size)]
    game = SnakeGameAI()

    for cur_gen in range(max_generations):
        game.generation = cur_gen
        for agent_num, agent in enumerate(agents):
            # Set colors
            game.color1 = agent.color1
            game.color2 = agent.color2

            # Set agent number
            game.agent_num = agent_num

            for cur_episode in range(1, max_episodes+1):
                run = True
                while run:
                    # Get old state
                    state_old = agent.get_state(game)

                    # Get move
                    final_move = agent.get_action(state_old)

                    # Perform move and get new state
                    reward, done, score = game.play_step(final_move)
                    state_new = agent.get_state(game)

                    # Train short memory
                    agent.train_short_memory(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, done)

                    # Remember
                    agent.remember(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, done)

                    # Snake died
                    if done:
                        run = False
                        # Train long memory, plot result
                        game.reset()
                        agent.episode = cur_episode
                        game.agent_episode = cur_episode
                        agent.train_long_memory()

                        if score > game.top_score:
                            game.top_score = score
                            agent.model.save()

                        total_score += score
                        game.mean_score = np.round((total_score / cur_episode), 3)
                        
                        print(f"Agent{game.agent_num}")
                        print(f"Episode: {cur_episode}")
                        print(f"Generation: {cur_gen}")
                        print(f"Score: {score}")
                        print(f"Top Score: {game.top_score}")
                        print(f"Mean: {game.mean_score}\n")
```